# Apache Wicket 6.12 Extensions Library

Tags: java, maven, wicket

I'm migrating a project form `Apache Wicket 1.5.7` to `Apache Wicket 6.12`.

I have a problem with the wicket extensions library, I don't know why it is not found, do i need to import it with maven, or is it in the core?

In this case it is about the NestedTree:

```
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.tree.NestedTree;
```

> This is the error: **The import org.apache.wicket.extensions cannot be resolved**

But no extension is found.

I'm sure the control exists in Wicket 6.x because of this documentation page: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/tree/package-summary.html

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load it as a separate maven dependency:

Here's the most current version, [taken from mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wicket/wicket-extensions)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>6.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Usually, the thing to do is to define a version property

```
<properties>                
    <wicket.version>6.11.0</wicket.version>
</properties>
```

and reference that from both wicket core and extensions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
    <version>${wicket.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>${wicket.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Will the extensions for 6.11 work with Wicket Core 6.12? Testing it now btw, but it's a little slow, thanks in advance:)

Comment: @NickN. actually, [wicket extensions 6.12.0 is already available on central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/wicket/wicket-extensions/), apparently mvnrepository.com hasn't indexed that yet, so you might as well use the same version for both

Comment: I did now, thanks a lot, I now have a lot of errors, because my old tree is not compatible, but that is the next step:)